# Lost access to ledger hidden wallet

Tags: passphrase, ledger-hardware-wallet, lost-wallet

Hi Yep I know I'm a prat but I am totally confused how this has happened. So I have my ledger 24 seed phrase. No issues there at all. But I set up the advanced feature on ledger I believe is called bip39 which allowed me to have a hidden wallet attached to this new passphrase. Unfortunately and I have absolutely no idea how but when I type in my passphrase the wallets with the money in don't show. I wrote down each passphrase (I had two, yes another mistake) and have no idea why they are not showing my wallet addresses with the money in. I guess I made a mistake and didn't write it down correctly or not at all but I only ever use the same passphrases so I either did a typo twice when I set it up or I've somehow forgotten them. I can see the wallet addresses on chain as I went into the exchange and copied the address and went to the explorer and the money is still sat there. I can honestly say I'm baffled as I'm not new to crypto either so very annoyed with myself. Is there anyway I can get access to these hidden wallets without the passphrase? I have the 24 word seed phrase. Someone on Reddit mentioned Ian Coleman? Anyway I am offering a small reward if I get it back. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is there anyway I can get access to these hidden wallets without the passphrase?**

None whatsoever.

> **I am offering a small reward if I get it back.**

Expect to be overwhelmed by offers from skilled confidence tricksters pretending to be recovery agents.

Answer (score 1):

In case you just have a typo, there is a good chance that you can recover your wallet with the help of [btcrecover](https://btcrecover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

They have different ways to configure possible typos. You can find more about them [here](https://btcrecover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/TUTORIAL/#typos).